# How to retrieve data from Firebase to pass into an array in angularfire2/version-5

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have some simple entries in Firebase like:

[image: this structure]

All I want is, to get these values (each percentage) and pass them into an array called *labels*. so that I can use that array in my code. That is my question.

Now, to me, it seemed easy but apparently it is not.

First of all what I faced is **@angularfire** version 5 differences in the examples(but easy to understand in their GitHub docs).
so secondly, I try to get data with:

```
this.items = db.list('/percentage').valueChanges();
```

so I do it and check it on the console.
[image: this is what I get]

then I check out other questions on SO and thirdly, in examples, I am told 'its asynchronous data so you should subscribe to it' I do subscribe and again log it in the console to see how my array would look like. [image: and this is what I get]
and of course, after that I check out more examples and oh, turns out I should **map()** it. then I do it with

```
this.labels = db.list('/percentage').valueChanges().map(res => this.labels = res);
```

:[image: and I get this]

I don't get any errors but I can't figure out a way to get this data as an array which would work for me.
I would be really glad if someone explain a way to me.
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`angularfire2` uses `Observables` by default. It's beneficial if you read up a bit on [rxjs library](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/).

> this.items = db.list('/percentage').valueChanges();

The above code will not work because `db.list().valueChanges()` is technically an `Observable`, as per your screenshot. Observable can be subscribed, but then again to assign the values you have to put your assignment statement in the callback function of the observables, **not** the observables itself. Here is how to do it:

```
db.list('/percentage')
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage. 
        this.labels = res;
    })
```

Note that for the above, there is no `this.lables = db.list()`.

On the other hand, `.map()` is just another `operators` in Observables. Operators are meant to use to manipulate the behaviour of the observables. How does each operator work is beyond the scope for this answer, I suggest reading up the docs.

#### Edit:

If you want to do some post processing on your data, that's where you will use `.map()`.

```
db.list('/percentage')
    .valueChanges()
    .map(res=>{
        // do some calculations here if you want to
        return res.map(eachlLabel=> eachlLabel + " Hello World")
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage. 
        this.labels = res;
    })
```

Alternatively you can do whatever post processing in your `subscribe` callback:

```
db.list('/percentage')
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage.
        //do your post processing to your res here.
        res = res.map(x=> x+ " Hello World");
        this.labels = res;
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really helped me understand things. One thing though, since this data is asynchronous, this data comes later than the time of my calculation code. How can I make it that my calculations start after I acquired this labels array?

Comment: @BlanketSniffer that's when you use `.map()`, to do manipulation to the data (aka calculations). Else, you can do it in the subscribe `callBack`. See edit

Answer (score 0):

you can shown your array on html page.

```
<p *ngFor="let item of items | async;>
 {{item}}
</p>
```

Comment: I know to use the template that way. but I want to store the data in an array so that I can use in my calculations.