# How to plot Firebase data with Chartjs in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, chart.js

I have a basic data with structure [image: like this] in my Firebase database.and in my angular app I want to use this data to chart.
this is my code:

```
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database'






@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
chart = []; 
arraytoPassChart = []

  @ViewChild('lineCanvas') lineCanvas;




  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }


  ionViewDidLoad() {

      this.db.list('/percentage')
        .valueChanges()
        .map(res => {
          // do some calculations here if you want to
          return res.map(eachlLabel => eachlLabel)
        })
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage. 
          this.arraytoPassChart.push(res);
        })

    this.chart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {

        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "My First dataset",
              fill: false,
              lineTension: 0.1,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
              borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
              borderCapStyle: 'butt',
              borderDash: [],
              borderDashOffset: 0.0,
              borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
              pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
              pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
              pointBorderWidth: 1,
              pointHoverRadius: 5,
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
              pointRadius: 1,
              pointHitRadius: 10,
              data: this.arraytoPassChart,// my data here, work when I type an array myself
              spanGaps: false,
            }
          ]
        }

      });



    }}
```

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087217/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-pass-into-an-array-in-angularfire2-version), somebody explained to me the right way to retrieve data from firebase. In my code when I log the result into the console I have the data as an array which I want to chart with **Chartjs**.

```
console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage.
```

but when the page is loaded it doesn't show the data.[image: link for empty chart] but when I type a data myself instead of passing the array it works. [image: see here]

I am really curious about what I am missing, I am suspicious that **Chartjs** is trying to chart before it has the data but I can't figure out a way to solve that too. I would be glad if there is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the chart within the subscribe,

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {

  this.db.list('/percentage')
    .valueChanges()
    .map(res => {
      // do some calculations here if you want to
      return res.map(eachlLabel => eachlLabel)
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)//should give you the array of percentage. 
      this.arraytoPassChart.push(res);
      this.makeChart();
    })
}

makeChart() {
  this.chart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ["January", ...],
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: makeChart(){... returning "can not find name makeChart"

Comment: Did you add makeChart as a method on the component?

Comment: You don't have to, it's just a bit tidier. You could put all the chart code where `this.makeChart` is.

Comment: The main point is, you are currently constructing the chart outside the `subscribe`, and you need to do it inside the subscribe, since the data won't be available until subscribe fires.

Comment: See @CozyAzure's second comment to yesterday's question, `you can do it in the subscribe callBack` - that applies to anything you do after the data fetch, it all has to be triggered within the subscribe.

Comment: Yes.it worked.Man I am so happy. Thank you very much

Comment: Its just funny, in documentation it says you should subscribe to it without thinking what a newby knows about what subscribe is.

Comment: Doesn't sound quite right... do you have a link to the page?

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/realtime-charts-with-plot-ly/  its on #updated cool-chart.ts part and well its not an actual docs but tutorial in official website. Says subscribe to it. and I thought it means like parsing json.

Comment: In the example code, they have method `topoChart()` called within the subscribe, so it is only invoked after the data is available - same as my suggested `makeChart()` method. You can think about it as a pipline, and topoChart() is 'attached' to the subscribe end of the pipe (hope that helps).

Comment: Yes I understood it in your third comment. Thanks